# Cycles, weird shadows appear on baked textures

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

I am having a bit of a trouble with the cycles bake. Every time i bake my texture's , a bunch of weird shadows appear in the baked textures as you can see from these pic's. The weird part is that i did pretty much the same thing to a model last night and it worked perfectly. Keep in mind that i am still just a beginner when it come's to cycles rendering.

Could this be a lighting problem or something like that?

--Before Bake--

[image: Before Bake]

--After Bake--
[image]

Comment: Is the image you are baking into itself used for the shader input ? On the left ? If yes, you may bake on another image

Comment: Well i tried your method and i still have the exact same problem. So no creating a new image to bake on didn't work.

Comment: Can you upload your file here ? http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/. With the texture if possible (pack it into the file)

Comment: I didn't allow me to upload to blend-exchange, so here's a dropbox link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8acjg962kuv7ot8/Blender%20Sword.zip?dl=0

Comment: need to apply scale

Comment: the point is you have several objects here... so if you are talking about the right / bottom right part. It has to be baked too. Select them both, I think it is ok or there is something else you want to say ? I have this result https://i.gyazo.com/069b65a5dfebc9dbc6aac34c85c9a2d7.png

Comment: Well i got pretty much all of the "shadows" removed by rotating the sword 90 degrees on z axis. At this point i have to say i have no idea what is going on anymore. So i guess i somehow managed to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dark areas on textures normally have one of the causes listed below:

1. You have overlapping geometry
2. You are baking combined textures, which means that you among others also bake the shadows.

According to the screenshots you provided we have both cases here.

[image]